# Any means to use Ubuntu/Linux to remove firmware restriction to boot from My Passport Essential 320G?

Tags: boot, usb, drive

Purchased WD My Passport Essential thinking it was a full service drive(i.e., backup and bootable for system crash and recovery) but NOT! Anybody know of work arounds? Firmware prevents from making the drive bootable.

Love is all there is...

Comment: I had a WD My passport Essential 500GB, and it do not have any restriction. Are you sure yours has it?

Comment: @ladnarlee - I'm not aware of a linux way to do this - however, you can do this via windows - http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/passport-vcd.html

Answer (score 2):

*(Comment to answer)*

I'm not aware of a linux way to do this - however, you can do this via windows

How to remove hidden Virtual CD (VCD) partitions on your Western Digital external disks

[Source](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/passport-vcd.html)